# Euclidean Geometry with Feet of Perpendicular

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with angle B = 90 degrees. Let D, E be points on AB such that BD = BC and AE = AC (they lie in the order B-E-D-A). Let F, G be the feet of perpendicular from E and D onto BC and AB respectively. If EF = 12 And DG = 11, what is DE?

While there are a ton of similar triangles, using their ratios did not lead to the nicest of equations (at least the way I did it). Given that this is a problem from a regional level olympiad with strict time controls (75 minutes for 8 questions) there is probably a clever way to utilize AC=AE and BC=BD which i seem to be missing

Comment: It is not clear D is on which side of $B$?

Comment: "Let F, G be the feet of perpendicular from E and F" maybe from D and E?

Comment: @DS haha sorry for not specifiying earlier. D, E lie in between B and C

Comment: If AE=AC then E cannot lie inside AB, because AC > AB (AC is the hypotenuse).

Comment: For the text to be meaningful, the right angle should be at C, and G should be the foot of the perpendicular from D to AC.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume, for the text to be meaningful, the right angle to be at C, and G to be the foot of the perpendicular from D to AC.

Set $AC=a$, $BC=b$, $AB=x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
From the similarity of triangles $ABC$, $ADG$, $EBF$ we get:
$$
(x-a):12=x:a,
\quad
(x-b):11=x:b,
$$
that is:
$$
a^2=(a-12)x,
\quad
b^2=(b-11)x.
$$
Adding these two equations we get:
$$
a^2+b^2=(a+b-23)x=x^2.
$$
whence:
$$
a+b-23=x
$$
and finally:
$$
DE=a+b-x=23.
$$

[image]